# Coefficients of Chebychev Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Is there a known formula for the coefficient of x^k in the nth chebychev polynomial of the first kind?

Comment: What about the 4th formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials ,"explicte expressions" ?

Comment: ah nice, did not see that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a paper that claims to do just this: [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/271362)

Comment: is there a way of viewing papers on that site?

Comment: I doubt it for this one.  IEEE is a real pain sometimes;  you have to go through your university or local library.

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=271362